# RowSelecting does not execute

Tags: acumatica

I use the RowSelecting event, in order to perform a BQL query.  I choose this event, since adding a BQL in RowSelected event is not advisable.  My purpose is to assign a non-DB bound field (a boolean), which is used to enable/disable a field.  During RowSelected event, the value is read, and a particular field is enabled/disabled, based on that value.

While using the debugger, I notice RowSelecting event does not fire when the form is first opened.  Cancel button causes event to fire.  Then I notice the api documentation...RowSelected & FieldSelecting events happen during sequence of events - display of record.  RowSelecting is not mentioned.

My goal is to disable a field based on some BQL.  What is the best way to perform the BQL and disable the field?  Should I use RowSelected?  Documentation says to avoid it.  In my case, I refer to SO invoice entry form...specifically SOInvoice DAC.

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the DAC in the Graph to add a PXUIEnabled Attribute to do this.

I updated my example to include a non-databound field that controls enabling and disabling another field.

In the SOInvoiceExt DAC Extension I have...

```
public class SOInvoiceExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.SO.SOInvoice>
{
    #region UsrExtRefNbrDisabled 
    [PXBool]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "ExtRefNbr Disabled?")]
    public virtual bool? UsrExtRefNbrDisabled { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrExtRefNbrDisabled : PX.Data.BQL.BqlBool.Field<usrExtRefNbrDisabled> { }
    #endregion
}
```

Then I added the new custom field to the screen. Ensure that you set CommitChanges to True.

Then in the Graph Extension, I merged the PXUIEnabled attribute with the CachedAttached event

```
[PXUIEnabled(typeof(Where<SOInvoiceExt.usrExtRefNbrDisabled, NotEqual<True>>))]
[PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Merge)]
protected virtual void SOInvoice_ExtRefNbr_CacheAttached(PXCache cache)
{ }
```

I was able to check/uncheck the box and it enabled/disabled the field.

Here is an old blog post on the subject: https://asiablog.acumatica.com/2016/11/pxuienabled-and-pxuirequired-attributes.html

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way to do this would be to make your NonDB field a calculated field and then setEnabled from RowSelected.
https://www.acumatica.com/blog/using-the-pxformula-attribute-to-simplify-your-code/

Otherwise, create a BQl query in FieldDefaulting.